# How to overwrite django app settings in unittests?

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

Django allows overwriting settings, when running tests through `SimpleTestCase.settings()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.settings). That works fine when I try to overwrite one of Django's settings.

The app I want to run tests for carries its own settings in an app-specific `settings.py` with the following structure to allow overwriting the app-specific settings in the project wide `settings.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
APP_SETTING1 = getattr(settings, 'APP_SETTING1', 'foo')
```

The following dummy code in a test shows the problem:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
from my_app import settings

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        with self.settings(APP_SETTING1='bar'):
            print(django_settings.APP_SETTING1)    # bar
            print(settings.APP_SETTING1)           # foo
```

Why isn't that working and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [django-zero-settings](https://github.com/aasmpro/django-zero-settings), it lets you define your default settings, and will update them with user settings provided, it also works fine in tests settings overrides, alongside that it auto import string, lets you define removed settings and pre-check user settings too.

as in your case, you can define app settings like this:

```py
from zero_settings import ZeroSettings

app_settings = ZeroSettings(
    key="APP",
    defaults={
        "SETTING1": "foo"
    },
)
```

then in your tests you can use it like:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
from my_app import app_settings

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        with self.settings(APP={"SETTING1": "bar"}):
            print(django_settings.APP["SETTING1"])    # bar
            print(app_settings.SETTING1)              # bar
            self.assertEqual(django_settings.APP["SETTING1"], app_settings.SETTING1)
```

because that `ZeroSettings` uses cache and will cache user settings on the first attempt to get key, you may need to set it off before getting keys, to make sure you get the latest updates:

```
app_settings = ZeroSettings(
    key="APP",
    defaults={
        "SETTING1": "foo"
    },
    use_cache=False,
)
```

or clear the cache manually:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        print(app_settings.SETTING1)                  # foo
        with self.settings(APP={"SETTING1": "bar"}):
            app_settings._clear_cache()
            print(django_settings.APP["SETTING1"])    # bar
            print(app_settings.SETTING1)              # bar
            self.assertEqual(django_settings.APP["SETTING1"], app_settings.SETTING1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should mock settings using unittest library incorporated into Django. Alternatively, you can do this, but it is better to patch those:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are good practices for handling multiple settings files. The basic rules are:

1) Do not import from `settings.py` file directly:

```
# BAD - avoid this
from app.settings import SOME_ENV
```

Because if in the end, someone will try to use custom settings some parts of the old settings will be applied somewhere.

```
# GOOD
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.SOME_ENV)
```

In this case, you could be sure that actual settings were used.

2) Split up settings files for different environments, usually, it accomplished via creating several files:

`settings/base.py`

```
DEBUG = False
AWS_STORAGE_PREFIX = 'local'
...
```

`settings/dev.py`

```
from settings.base import *

DEBUG = True
AWS_STORAGE_PREFIX = 'dev'
DATABASE = {# your settings for dev env}
...
```

It is also quite usual to create a separated file for test runner because it gives you more [power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799061/speeding-up-django-testing) of controlling your test env and so on:

```
python manage.py test --settings=app.settings.testrunner
```

Test instance has bound settings' context manager, so you can override any variables that you need for testing:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        # Old settings
        with self.settings(SOME_ENV_VAR='overridden'):
            # Overridden settings
            pass
        ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it directly in  apps using a certain setting

settings.py:

```
TEST_ENVIRONMENT_SETTING = True  # Test setting for my app
```

apps.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        if getattr(settings, 'TEST_ENVIRONMENT_SETTING', False):
            # Do stuff or not do stuff
```

Or you can directly set this setting in your TestCase using

```
setattr(settings, 'TEST_ENVIRONMENT_SETTING', True)
```

Comment: Well, I'm searching for a cleaner solution, as I don't to put references to the tests in the productive code.

Comment: Oh and regarding directly overwriting the settings:
    You shouldn’t alter settings in your applications at runtime.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

Answer (score -2):

I'm struggling with the same problem, and I think the only solution is to change approach and use only django.conf.settings directly.

The reason is that if you use a custom settings, your custom settings is taken too early from settings, before override_settings or TestCase.settings is called.